# convolutional neural network in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am new to python, so the challenges for me currently are:

- Clear, simple code, trying to follow standard practices
- Useful comments,
- Use types (for better understanding of input/output relationships.)

Apart from that, the basic task here is to create a simple **convolutional network** to **calculate rotation** in a dataset of images.

I have purposely split the network in two pieces, backbone and head, for clarity and learning purposes.

I'd appreciate any criticism, both in style and related to the task at hand.

```py
from torch import nn

class SpotRotBackbone(nn.Module):
    """
      Backbone (first part) of the spot rotated neural network
      It is just a convolution.
      Args: None
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2))
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten() 
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        return x


class SpotRotHead(nn.Module):
    """
    This is the head of the model, which is responsible for the classification of the image.
    Args:
        input_size: the size of the input image
    """
    def __init__(self, input_size:int):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 128)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 4)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    """
    A PyTorch neural network for image classification.

    Args:
        input_size: Size of the 2D dimension i.e width or height (we consider square images only).
    """

    def __init__(self, input_size:int):
        super().__init__()
        self.backbone = SpotRotBackbone()
        self.head = SpotRotHead(input_size*input_size*16)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.backbone(x)
        x = self.head(x) 
        return x

from torchinfo import summary
summary(NeuralNetwork(416), (1, 3, 416,416))
```

Also, the last line prints:

```
==========================================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Output Shape              Param #
==========================================================================================
NeuralNetwork                            [1, 4]                    --
├─SpotRotBackbone: 1-1                   [1, 2768896]              --
│    └─Conv2d: 2-1                       [1, 32, 416, 416]         896
│    └─ReLU: 2-2                         [1, 32, 416, 416]         --
│    └─Dropout: 2-3                      [1, 32, 416, 416]         --
│    └─Conv2d: 2-4                       [1, 64, 416, 416]         18,496
│    └─ReLU: 2-5                         [1, 64, 416, 416]         --
│    └─MaxPool2d: 2-6                    [1, 64, 208, 208]         --
│    └─Flatten: 2-7                      [1, 2768896]              --
├─SpotRotHead: 1-2                       [1, 4]                    --
│    └─Linear: 2-8                       [1, 128]                  354,418,816
│    └─ReLU: 2-9                         [1, 128]                  --
│    └─Dropout: 2-10                     [1, 128]                  --
│    └─Linear: 2-11                      [1, 4]                    516
==========================================================================================
Total params: 354,438,724
Trainable params: 354,438,724
Non-trainable params: 0
Total mult-adds (Units.GIGABYTES): 3.71
==========================================================================================
Input size (MB): 2.08
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 132.91
Params size (MB): 1417.75
Estimated Total Size (MB): 1552.74
==========================================================================================
```